# IOS AVFoundation - avcapturevideopreviewlayer preview freezes on first frame

Tags: ios, avfoundation, freeze, preview

This is strange and beyond me.  If I take the AVCAM example from Apple and paste it on my app (along with all files, declarations, etc), I can use the camera just fine. The app captures stills, video, save, autofocus, etc. Everything works great but one thing, the preview layer (to see what the camera is pointing at) freezes on the first frame right when it loads and stays frozen. 
Here's the code from Apple that goes into the viewDidLoad of my main controller:

```
if ([self captureManager] == nil) {
         AVCamCaptureManager *manager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];
         [self setCaptureManager:manager];
         [manager release];

         [[self captureManager] setDelegate:self];

         if ([[self captureManager] setupSession]) {

              // Create video preview layer and add it to the UI
              AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[[self captureManager] session]];
              UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
              CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
              [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

              CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
              [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

              if ([newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported]) {
                  [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
              }

              [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

              [viewLayer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

              [self setCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];
              [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer release];


         // Start the session. This is done asychronously since 
         //    -startRunning doesn't return until the session is running.
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];     });
          }       
}
```

Now get this:  In reverse, instead of pasting Apple's code into my app, I decided to paste my code into Apple's AVCAM to see if that would work. After moving lots of files and basically turning the AVCAM into my experimental app, everything works just fine.  Both projects (1- Apple's AVCAM with my added code   and  2 - my original project with AVCAM added code) have the exact same files and the exact same code. No joke. The class headers and implementation files of both projects are identical. However, on my original project the preview layer freezes and stays frozen. But on AVCAM original project the preview layer works.  So I'm checking frameworks, build and linking options, SDK version, etc... I suspect it's a project setup somewhere but I can't figure this out.  I really don't want to start on top of AVCAM every time I need this.

Has anybody run into this? preview layer frozen at first frame right after view loads.

Any clues?  (btw, I'm on SDK 5.1,  armv7, running on device).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: forgot to mention... I did open up the XIB and added a UIView linked to the File Owner's  videoPreviewView. So looking at my XIB file, the view setup also looks identical to the AVCam example.

Comment: have you got the solution. I am running in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... Putting here in case somebody needs it... 
The problem was the connections in the MainWindow.xib.

- solution part 1

If you open MainWindow.xib, you should see least 2 objects:

the "App View Controller"  (where App is your app name)

and the "Window" object.

click the Window object. 
view the "Connections Inspector",
under the OUTLETS section there is a "rootViewController" outlet. 
Mine was not mapped to anything. So I clicked that outlet connection and dragged it all the way to the "App View Controller" object in the list of objects.
Now the "WINDOW" object has a connection from the rootViewController to the App View Controller. 
If I click on the "App View Controller" object and look at the connections inspector, I also see the reverse connection from the "referencing outlet" rootViewController to the Window object.

- solution part 2

not all applications have an App Delegate in the list of objects of MainWIndow.xib.
If your app doesn't have a delegate for the view controller, then you're done. 
If your app does have a delegate for the view controller, then you have one more step:
Still looking at MainWindow.xib, click your App Delegate object and look at the Connections Inspector.  Under "OUTLETS" section, if you see a connection from viewController to App View Controller, delete that connection (click the little x to delete it). 
That should be all. Other alternatives, if you don't use the delegate at all, you could just delete this.

After the steps above, my app works like a charm.
The preview layer displays real-time without freezing.

note: This solution disables the delegate. So some of the methods like applicationDidEnterBackground will no longer have any effect on your view controller. You might need to play around with the connections a little more if you need to get the Delegate methods working again without freezing the videopreviewlayer. Maybe create a second viewcontroller for your project for the video stuff. who knows... For my needs I just deleted the delegate.

I hope this helps.

Comment: PS: Did not run into this issue when using storyboards.  So for extremely basic apps, I'd just go without an app delegate.  For the more complex ones, I'd use storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.
I was using an AVAudioPlayer to play sounds in conjunction with my AVCaptureManager.
I had originally set the AVAudioPlayer AVAudioSessionCategory to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.
When I changed it to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, the freezing stopped.